# Auto focus on Modal View

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to accomplish is auto focus on the modal view. To explain it a bit further. I want it so that when I click on my image on my web page and it opens up the modal view it should automatically focus on the modal allowing me to scroll up and down without me having to click on the image to bring it on focus to be able to scroll up and down using my keyboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Nld.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw6HU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyM0Y.jpg

*Follow up I gave links above to pictures. Hopefully its easier now. Cheers*

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Advise Column
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Modal.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento|Risque|Unkempt" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1 id="top-hd-01" class="page-header">PICK A SENSEI!</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-placement">
            <img src="Batman.jpg" alt="BATMAN" class="advise-page-img-sizing adv-page-img-modalling" id="adv-page-img-01">
            <figcaption class="img-captioning">BATMAN</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-placement">
            <img src="Robin.jpg" alt="ROBINS" class="advise-page-img-sizing adv-page-img-modalling" id="adv-page-img-02">
            <figcaption class="img-captioning">ROBIN</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 img-placement">
            <img src="Joker.jpg" alt="JOKER" class="advise-page-img-sizing adv-page-img-modalling" id="adv-page-img-03">
            <figcaption class="img-captioning">JOKER</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" id="modal-cross-button" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="modal-adv-page-img">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script src="Modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#top-hd-01
{
    font-family: 'Unkempt', cursive;
}

.img-placement
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

.advise-page-img-sizing
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 350px;
}

.img-captioning
{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Risque', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;

}


/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.adv-page-img-modalling {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.adv-page-img-modalling:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
   /* max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 700px;*/
}

#modal-cross-button
{
    position: fixed;
}

.sensei-answers, .sensei-questions, .sensei-quote
{
    font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
}

.sensei-questions
{
    font-size: 28px;
}

.sensei-answers
{
    font-size: 22px;
    color: darkblue;
}

.sensei-quote
{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ff751b;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-adv-page-img");

var img1 = document.getElementById("adv-page-img-01")
var img2 = document.getElementById("adv-page-img-02")
var img3 = document.getElementById("adv-page-img-03")

var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

img1.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img2.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img3.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell what the 'shown.bs.modal' is for. I assumed the 'shown.bs.modal' would be for when the modal is displayed or opened. I attempted using your function but I didn't get a positive result.

Comment: sorry, I thought you're using bootstrap modal (I've seen `#myModal` and assume it was a bootstrap default). That not applies for what you're doing. Have you tried to apply focus in one of the elements inside the modal?

Comment: Oh I'll look up the bootstrap modal and see if that works. B/c I am using bootstrap. Also I'm going to attempt focusing some kind of element inside the modal next.

Answer (score 0):

The `autofocus` attribute won't work in this case, since this will fire on page load. However, you can easily tackle this problem with some JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('modal').focus(); // vanilla JS
$('#modal').focus(); // jQuery
```

Make sure to trigger one of these functions as soon as the modal is openend.

Comment: I tried both vanilla JS and JQuery. I attempted to trigger the vanilla JS in img1.onclick function after displaying the modal using modal.display = block. With JQuery I attempted to do the same. I used alert function to make sure my triggers were working. Didn't work though. I'll keep trying, I have a feeling I'm doing something stupid hence its not working as wanted.